# Notepad ++ snippet

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I've found an error with a statement I've been using and I was wondering if anyone could help me break it down and find a fix.

When using these statements in the `Replace` function, I've noticed it replaces ALL letters, not just the one or format.

Example:

```
.*[ing|;]$
```

All words ending in `I`, `N`, `G` AND `ING` will be replaced, not just words ending in `ING` like I would prefer.

This is problematic for condensing my lists and I could use a workaround if anyone can assist me.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets represent any of the characters within the brackets, so that `[ing]` represents any single 'i', 'n', or 'g'. You're probably looking for `.*(ing|;)$`, where the parentheses represent a specific substring. The pipe still represents a disjunction such that a string ending in either 'ing' or ';' is matched by that expression.